# Google maps API v2 makes size of APK bigger than old version

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

there is an app use Google map API v2
After Build Signed Release APK, File length is Too Huge
i build "**HelloWord**" Project to measure Length And Add google_play_services_lib to project
File length Up To 2.2 Mb more than "**HelloWord**" APK

Also Repository And google play services from SKD Manager had Updated.

I use Android Studio IDE (Gradle) And Import all google-play-services.
is it possible to import **part of it** ?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse or Android Studio?

Comment: How does your dependency look like? Are you importing all google-play-services or just a part of it?

Comment: @MarekSebera I import all of it to my project.

Comment: See: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using AS and Gradle as build script / dependency management

To import whole Google Play Services you're using dependency like this:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
```

Which includes all the services resources and classes, it's huge list:

```
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.8.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0 -> 22.2.1
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.8.0
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:7.8.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:7.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:7.8.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appstate:7.8.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:7.8.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:22.2.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0 -> 22.2.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:7.8.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:7.8.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.8.0
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0 (*)
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.8.0
|    |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:7.8.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:7.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.8.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.8.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:7.8.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:7.8.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.8.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:7.8.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:7.8.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:7.8.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.8.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.8.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:7.8.0
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0 (*)
```

To downsize it, you have three options:

- Add only part of it, you need, eg. `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.8.0`
- Exclude parts you don't want

like this:

```
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0') {
    exclude module: 'play-services-fitness'
    exclude module: 'play-services-games'
    exclude module: 'play-services-wallet'
    exclude module: 'play-services-safetynet'
    exclude module: 'play-services-appinvite'
    exclude module: 'play-services-wearable'
    exclude module: 'play-services-cast'
}
```

- Or use Proguard (minifyEnabled), which should trim from the resulting APK resources and classes, that are not used or reffered to

Comment: Thank You size of APK Down to 3.72 Mb From 5.1 Mb

Comment: Also you can unzip final APK and see what is the biggest part. If its `classes.dex` file, you should try proguard minification, see: https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-shrinking